# Is there anything to do about an unfair downvote on a clear question?

Tags: support, questions, downvotes

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74502597/13695921) is a question about something not clear in of the official Microsoft documentation about C#.

The first comment on that question clearly mention that something is actually missing from the documentation:

> "It's a shame the tutorial doesn't make that clear at all, of course.
> I've sent feedback about that".

Because of that thing that is unclear, the application that the documentation gives a tutorial on how to run is not working.

The question got two downvotes. This thing happened previously on also some fair questions. Now the website won't accept new questions.

Can anything be done?

Comment: I'm unclear what makes these down votes "unfair".

Comment: You have 18 deleted questions contributing to your asking ban

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas what makes the downvote fair ? It's a question about following a tutorial and something not working.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine mentioned in the question that this thing happened previously. The deleted question have comments suggesting fair answers..

Comment: Friendly reminder, we all had begun somehow. OP asking for a specific programming question, points to documentation, states the error and shows a minimal reproducible example in his question, even if not directly copy and pasted in the question. It might be an duplicate but not necessarily a downvote. To your ban, that is unfortunate but 18 deleted questions is an award winning goal and you received the price.

Comment: There are a couple of links on that page to [.NET CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/), which does tell you that you need to run `dotnet new console` to create the example files.  Probably not a great introduction for the "new to programming" audience, it seems to be geared to somewhere between "C# developer" and "previous version of .NET developer" audience.

Comment: @Thingamabobs The problem is with it "it might be". It's not a duplicate, and there is no reproducible example in this case. And for the other 18 deleted questions it's the same case.

Comment: @AnonCoward Yes this will create the files. But if the files were to be created manually, there is still some missing information. This question rather is not about the solution of the linked question.

Comment: Right, which is why I pointed it out.  That information was immediately clear to me reading the documentation.  You appear to be noting an issue with the documentation, in which case, open a bug with the provider of the documentation.  At least that's how I read the linked SO post.

Comment: @AnonCoward No, the question didn't point out an issue in the documentation. The comment did. There are many ways of creating an application. It's clear that there is a way with `dotnet new console` but the question is about the other way of not using `dotnet new console`. That other way wasn't working.

Comment: *And for the other 18 deleted questions it's the same case.* -- really? Why didn't you came earlier ? It is little late now, don't you think?

Comment: "But they didn't mention anything about the file names if it matters, their location, etc."  That's not a comment about the documentation?  Then I'm confused.  You didn't mention you knew about the other command, and wanted an alternative.  It's not clear to me what the SO post is asking.  That's confusing.  If you disagree, fine, but understand, this confusion exists, and people do not react to confusion with upvotes.

Comment: @Thingamabobs It's the same problem of the downvotes of the linked questions. <i>really? Why didn't you came earlier ? It is little late now, don't you think?</i> What does this have to do with this question ?

Comment: You asking about releasing your ban --*Now the website won't accept new questions. Anything that can be done ?*-- or not ? When you have gathered 18 deleted questions related to it, an unfortunate event won't convince anyone to take action.

Comment: @AnonCoward Understand that there are confusions and there is no problem. But isn't this the purpose of comments rather than the answer to clarify if there are confusions ? "But they didn't mention anything about the file names if it matters, their location, etc." that was leading to "I created 2 files: 'test.cs' containing the hello world and 'test' which is of type xml. Both are the only files under the same directory.". Its not pointing to something missing it's purpose to clarify that a solution has been tried.

Comment: _"Now the website won't accept new questions. Anything that can be done?"_ Start by improving your questions with a score of <=0 as well as any deleted questions that you think can be improved and undeleted. That's the _only_ thing that can be done that will have a _significant_ impact on getting you out of the question ban. Read the answer in the linked post for more guidance. There are other options (like providing good-quality answers, making good-quality edits, or waiting 6 months to ask your next question) but none of that will help you get out of the question ban quickly.

Comment: "But isn't this the purpose of comments rather than the answer to clarify if there are confusions" It's one use, some prefer to downvote instead because they often immediately get told they read the question wrong, and grow tired of such attempts at helping backfiring.

Comment: Being told they read the question wrong isn't even the worst consequence. The worst-case scenario (which does occasionally happen) is flat out death threats. General insults are far more common and happen on a daily basis. People are the reason we can't have nice things, including just general attempts at help on bad questions or answers. It's still sad how poorly people react to genuine attempts at constructive criticism

Comment: Beware the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) or our on-site version of the [Streisand effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect) where asking a question on meta about a stackoverflow question brings additional attention to the question, possibly positive attention and possibly negative attention.

Comment: Proof-reading questions carefully also helps - there's a *huge* difference between "minimal .Net application **now** working" and "minimal .Net application **not** working" which is what I assume you meant it to say...

Comment: “This thing happened previously on also some fair questions. Now the website won't accept new questions.” - It happened 18 times, and 18 times, the question was deleted? You asking 18 questions and those 18 questions being deleted are the reason, your currently question banned. I don’t trust your opinion that those 18 questions were high quality because if they were they wouldn’t have been deleted. Of course I suspect you deleted some of those questions because you mistakenly thought deleting the question wouldn’t result in a question ban. How many questions did you delete exactly?

Answer (score 17):

A common reason for a downvote is written everywhere and in particular as the tooltip for the downvote button - "does not show any research effort". As a result, it is the first thing to check if your post shows "research effort".

---

One common problem demonstrated in the linked post is no attempt to search/read about the error message, which for most errors will give at least some information.

If you would search for the error like https://www.bing.com/search?q=Couldn%27t+find+a+project+to+run.+Ensure+a+project+exists+in you get decent number of articles, including *[Can't run code using the 'dotnet' run command in Visual Studio. "Couldn't find a project to run"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56775156/cant-run-code-using-dotnet-run-command-in-visual-studio-couldnt-find-a-proje)*. Reading those probably would have removed the need to ask the question in the first place, but at least showing that you tried to search for the error message would help.

---

Another common problem is picking seeming random documentation/how-to guide to start learning (usually "I retyped text barely visible in some random video and it does not work", but using strange sites/documentation at the wrong level happens too). While indeed it would be nice if the overview section for .NET gives complete samples, it is not the only place for "how to start with .NET or dotnet tool and trying some other more targeted guides would be a good idea to do and include in the question.

---

There is another less common reason for downvotes - completely unclear why the question is asked or why it is asked on SO. The linked question reads as "this documentation is incomplete/incorrect" - SO is not the right place to report such issue (there is a link on the documentation page [to leave "Feedback"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/introduction#feedback) as well as review [existing feedback](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%229d3015b4-cba1-0956-9ec7-4154dbb74d93%22&in=body) - which already had some similar complains). While probably vote to close as "unclear" would be more appropriate for such an interpretation of the question, downvoting is not wrong (as "not useful").

Not focusing on the problem with documentation may be another way to improve the question. Changing it to be more of a "how-to" question could be an option, also I don't think that would help - file names for project files in C# have not changed in 20+ years and it should not be too hard to find how to name one. For example, reading documentation on the [`dotnet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet) tool could help to figure out how to create a new console project and see what files are there.